# TableViewCell with UITextView not aligned and cutted until scolling

Tags: xcode, swift, uitableview, text-alignment

I've a TableViewCell with a UITextView, which content is not aligned and cutted at bottom at the first display:

[image]

When I scroll down and then up to the top, everything is fine:

[image]

My `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to get the content from a `fetchedResultsController` is simple:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TextViewCell") as! TextViewCell
    let data = self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! NSManagedObject
    let text = data.valueForKey("textDu")!.description
    cell.textContentView.text = text
    return cell
}
```

How can I get the result after scrolling after start???

Comment: can you post your hieghtForRowAtIndexPath method?

Comment: I only set the UITableViewAutomaticDimension at viewDidLoad (?)

    override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 89

        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }

Answer (score 1):

Use `sizeToFit()` after adding content to your `textContentView`.

```
cell.textContentView.text = text
cell.textContentView.sizeToFit()
```

Make sure for sizing cell

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {

       super.viewDidLoad()

       NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self,
           selector: "onContentSizeChange:",
           name: UIContentSizeCategoryDidChangeNotification,
           object: nil)

       tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 89
       tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

   }

   override func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool)  {
       super.viewDidDisappear(animated)

       NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
   }

   func onContentSizeChange(notification: NSNotification) {
       tableView.reloadData()
   }
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: @UlliHeinelt check the constraints also, it should be with the blue lines (not red lines) no errors should be in your constraints

Comment: @Ashid Kakkad: what constraints do you mean?

Comment: @UlliHeinelt I am Ashish Kakkad :) . and please check autolayout guide https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html for constraints

Comment: sorry Ashish :-(
I've 2 vertical constaints: from textView.top to Superview.top and from Superview.bottom to textView.bottom And 2 horizontal constraints: leading & trailing

Answer (score 0):

In conjunction with @Ashish Kakkad's answer you may want to try to set heightDimensions in `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear`:

```
yourTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 30.0 // Put a real estimate here
yourTableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

Comment: Thanks :) I have added that as same time you have given answer. Thank you

Comment: how does this differ from @Ashish Kakkad solution?

Comment: @Ashish Kakkad
doesn't change anything. I dio this in the init() of the **superclass**. It's a inherited class

Comment: @Cocoadelica what do you mean with **text box**?

Comment: Hi, sorry, I meant the UITextView

Comment: I've 2 vertical constaints: from textView.top to Superview.top and from Superview.bottom to textView.bottom
And 2 horizontal constraints: leading & trailing

Answer (score 0):

Use auto layout code to tie the bottom of the cells `contentView` to the bottom of the text box. When the text box resizes it'll expand the cell with it.
This is in addition to Asish's correct suggestion about automatic cell heights and is quite a high level suggestion as you need to do a few things to get auto layout working right in tableview cells but there's ample examples on that out on the web.

Comment: what do you mean with text box?

Comment: If you're using a custom cell you need to setup auto layout inside the cell, on the left hand side of the storyboard where it has your view hierarchy you need to setup constraints in the cell between the uitextview and the contentView of the cell.

Comment: I've 2 vertical constaints: from textView.top to Superview.top and from Superview.bottom to textView.bottom And 2 horizontal constraints: leading & trailing

Answer (score 0):

oh, oh. Think I found something. I removed the existing contraints and then I've tried to "add missing constaints". The result was thas the error "Failed to automatically update constraints". Seem's I've a problem with my storyboard-file...